# Add Event on VueNumeric

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

good day everyone,

I'm planning to use [vue numeric](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-numeric) in my project. but it seems I can't attached an event into it.

**VUE NUMERIC**

```
<vue-numeric
        v-on:keypress="test"
        separator=","
        class="form-control"
        step="any"
        v-model.number="detail.qty"
        ></vue-numeric>
```

**METHOD**

```
 methods:{
     test(){
           alert(1);
     }
 }
```

if anyone have any idea it would be a really great help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late, but I found this solution in the vue-numeric GitHub repository:  https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-numeric/issues/72

It uses the '.native' feature to listen to the keypress event.  It is described in more detail here:  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components .

I was able to add the 'keypress' event processing to your code by adding:

```
v-on:keypress.native="test"
```

I also modified your "test" method to look like:

```
        test: function(evt){
          alert(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue-numeric exposes/emits only 3 events - input, focus and blur. It does not emit `keypress` events.

Comment: you think it's possible to add a custom event on the core? to emit keypress event?

Comment: You will have to either move the component from `node_modules` into your project folder so that NPM won't override your changes, or you have to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package to apply your patch over the original component